# Unauthorized connection after Authenticating with HTTPCLIENT

Tags: java, http

So I'm getting `Unauthorized error` after authorizing with http client. The website im trying to access has `NTLM` authentication. If someone could help with this issue it would be appreciated.

```
public class ClientAuthentication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        try {
            httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                    new AuthScope("website", 80),
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://cdg5.intranet.bell.ca/BlackFoot/Ont/");

            System.out.println("executing request" + httpget.getRequestLine());
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());

            if (entity != null) {
                System.out.println("Response content length: " + entity.getContentLength());
            }
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);



   } finally {
            // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
            // shut down the connection manager to ensure
            // immediate deallocation of all system resources
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the result im getting

> "executing requestGET http://cdg5.intranet.bell.ca/BlackFoot/Ont/
>   HTTP/1.1
>
> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Response content length: 1656"